# Join fetch strategy does not work since spring-data-jpa 3.0.0

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm facing an issue since upgrading Spring boot 2.7.10 to 3.0.0 (problem occurs still in 3.0.5). I first thought the problem was on Hibernate side but everything works when I'm just using `EntityManager`, but the problems occurs when using `CrudRepository`.

I have two entities with a bidirectionnal @OneToMany relationship.
The @ManyToOne is in a Embeddable class. My queries are with "join fetch" strategy to load the association directly and avoid a N+1 select.

Before upgrading, everything was ok, but now the association is not loaded and I got an exception when I try to access on this association with my result entity.

**Important : the problem happens only if the @ManyToOne is in a Embeddable class.**

Here is a simplified part of my entities :

```java
@Table(name = "sellers")
@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SellerEntity implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SellerEntityPK pk;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return pk.getId();
    }

    public CompanyEntity getCompany() {
        return pk.getCompany();
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Builder
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SellerEntityPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CompanyEntity company;

    private String id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return company.getName() + "+" + id;
    }
}
```

```java
@Table(name = "company")
@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.company")
    @Default
    private Set<SellerEntity> sellers = new java.util.HashSet<>(0);

}
```

The query :

```java
@Query("""
            select distinct s from SellerEntity s
            join fetch s.pk.company c
            where c.name = :companyName
            """)
    Optional<SellerEntity> findSellersWithCompany(String companyName);
```

Runtime code :

```java
Optional<SellerEntity> postFound = sellerRepository.findSellersWithCompany("My first company");
 String country = postFound.get().getCompany().getCountry();
```

The SQL does not contain the "join" on the table "company" :

```sql
select distinct s1_0.company_name,s1_0.id,s1_0.name from sellers s1_0 where s1_0.company_name=?
```

but before upgrading, the sql request was doing the join and everything worked fine

```sql
select distinct sellerenti0_.company_name as company_3_6_0_, sellerenti0_.id as id1_6_0_, companyent1_.name as name1_0_1_, sellerenti0_.name as name2_6_0_, companyent1_.country as country2_0_1_ from sellers sellerenti0_ inner join company companyent1_ on sellerenti0_.company_name=companyent1_.name where companyent1_.name=?
```

Error :

```java
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.jpajoinfetch.seller.CompanyEntity#My first company] - no Session
```

Does anyone face the same problem ? Do you have any suggestion please ?

Comment: If someone faces the same problem, the solution is here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2910